# How to solve IllegalStateException while calling timerService in stateless session bean class

Tags: java, timer, ejb-3.1

I am facing the below Exception while creating a timer service in stateless session bean call. i am using ebj3.1  annotations for the TimerService and sessionContext.

> Exception occured while calling sessionContext
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010193]Illegal call to
>   EJBContext method. The bean is in "null" state. It cannot perform
>   'getting the Timer Service' action(s). Refer to the EJB specification
>   for more details. 03 Sep 2014 11:58:53,782 DEBUG CSIDNotificationSB
>   []: Exception occured while calling sessionContext
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010193]Illegal  call to
>   EJBContext method. The bean is in "null" state. It cannot perform
>   'getting the Timer Service' action(s). Refer to the EJB specification
>   for more  details.

Below is the code i used to create a timer.

```
TimerService timerService = sessionContext.getTimerService(); 
Timer timer =timerService.createTimer(Long.valueOf(TimerInterval);
```

> @Stateless(mappedName = "CSIDNotificationSB", name =
>   "CSIDNotificationSB") 
>   @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) 
>   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
>
> @Resource     TimerService timerService;  SessionContext
>   sessionContext;

Please help me resolve the Exception.

Comment: can you show the annotations etc.. also?

Comment: please see the annotations details

Comment: I think you should remove this line: TimerService timerService = sessionContext.getTimerService(); you get the timerservice from resource injection already

Comment: i have tried the same as you said. But still i am getting the same issue

Comment: perhaps better to reduce your bean to a minimal example where you still get the problem. You are not trying to do stuff in the constructor?